# Coherent state and planewave: energy finite in the first but not in the second

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-optics

Coherent state are supposed to represent Fourier modes of classical states of light. In free space : plane waves, in cavity : stationnary waves.

Classically, a plane wave has an infinite energy. Indeed, integrating $|E|^2$ on all the space will give a diverging energy.

However, as soon as I choose $\alpha$ finite, the energy of a coherent state will be finite: $\hbar \omega |\alpha|^2$.

How can the two visions thus be compatible ?

Comment: I might be wrong about this, so correct me if I am, but I thought it was only laser light (that is, light emitted due to a coherent resonant mode) that was described by a coherent state, and not just any light...

Comment: @StarBuck What is your reasoning that a plane wave can be represented by a coherent state? What is your definition or understanding of coherent sate?

Comment: @AboveThreshold Coherent state are superposition of fock state where the population of those fock state verifies a poissonian distribution. They represent classical states of light corresponding to plane wave in free space or stationnary wave in cavity. Take a look at http://paristech.institutoptique.fr/site.php?id=341&fileid=11449 1.4.2

Comment: @Philip take a look at my previous comment. If you average the electric field operator on a coherent state you will find the expression of a classical plane wave (it is not the case for fock states for example as the average value on the electric field in $0$ in all space). $\langle \alpha | \widehat{E} | \alpha \rangle \propto |\alpha| \sin(\omega t - kx)$ with $\widehat{E}$ the quantized electric field.

Comment: Actually I think the answer is that when we quantize we invoke a finite volume of quantization that must be put to infinity at the end of the calculation. So maybe that for $\alpha$ finite, it represent a plane wave...with 0 amplitude. And we must allow $\alpha$ to behave like: $\alpha \rightarrow \alpha \sqrt{V}$ so that when we take the infinite volume limite the value of the electric field doesn't vanish (but it correspond to infinite number of excitation which would be consistant)

Comment: @StarBucK Yeah I checked the reference. I agree with your last comment. Volume quantization make the plane wave finite in space, and most of the time the number of photons is assumed to be finite. The opposite case, the classical case, is like a thermodynamic limit in statistical mechanics that density is kept constant while the volume and the number of particles are infinitely large. In the case of photon, as far as I know, It can be taken as classical limit when there are so many photons in a quite big volume. I do not know how many is needed in a how big volume, specific numbers, though.